# How Does a React Snippet get Turned into Browser Javascript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, babeljs

The React getting started page contains the following snippet

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>Hello React!</title>
    <script src="build/react.js"></script>
    <script src="build/react-dom.js"></script>
    <script src="https://npmcdn.com/babel-core@5.8.38/browser.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="example"></div>
    <script type="text/babel">
      ReactDOM.render(
        <h1>Hello, world!</h1>,
        document.getElementById('example')
      );
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

The code included

```
<script type="text/babel">
  ReactDOM.render(
    <h1>Hello, world!</h1>,
    document.getElementById('example')
  );
</script>
```

is **not** valid browser javascript -- the inline `<h1>Hello, world!</h1>` would crash if ran in a javascript context, and the `<script/>` tag has a `type` of `text/babel`.

Conceptually, I get that React is using [babel](https://babeljs.io/), a compiler/transpiler, and that code inside of `text/babel` will be treated as babel, and transformed by *something* into valid javascript.

What less clear to me is how this transformation happens, and which part(s) of the above snippet gets transformed by babel, and which parts get transformed by React.

I realize understanding the framework on this level isn't required to use it.

I also realize that an in-depth answer probably goes beyond the scope of a single Stack Overflow answer.  While in-depth answers are welcome, all I'm really looking for is the high level overview of which libraries provide which magic in the above snippet, and what I consider magic are javascript features not offered by the browser.  i.e., something like

1. Babel scans for `text/babel` nodes, transforming above snippet into x,y,z, turning the DOM nodes into javascript that looks like X
2. React takes above and further transforms it in x,y,z ways, leaving browser with old javascript it understands.

but with x,y,z filled in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope this suffices:

Anything transpiled to ES5 is totally acceptable by your browser. Babel transpiles what you rightfully said is non-js to ES5.

Take a look at the compiled result. Any funky html tags <> have been turned into function calls of the sort: React.createElement("label", {className: "label"}) which is as JS as it gets.

React is a library like any other that contains function like createElement - which does DOM manipulation much like jquery (albeit more optimized with something called a shadow dom)

That's it.

Comment: your babel config file should have an input and an output. Also, you can open your browser developer tools and see the final javascript file that was downloaded.

Comment: also if you are using the CLI: babel script.js --out-file script-compiled.js

Comment: Apologies, was mid-edit on my comment when you answered.  There's two questions that fall out of this.  The first, how to see the output from the compiler, you've answered (implicit in your answer was not using inline text/babel, but pre-compiling scripts).  The second question though is -- how does babel know about React?  Is babel hard coded for this, or is there some sort of plugin the React team added for babel that makes babel do more than a straight es5 to es6 transformation?

Comment: ah that's a good question, and it seems the answer isn't readily in my brain, i'm off to read.... ahh its a plugin: npm install babel-plugin-transform-react-jsx

Comment: Thanks -- for anyone that comes along later, it looks like babel's core ships with React as something built-in.  i.e. the plugin mentioned by is part of their core builds.  You can see this in the un-minified version of browser.js (https://npmcdn.com/babel-core@5.8.38/browser.js).

Answer (score 2):

The JSX gets *transpiled* into a function call, which invokes the [`React.createElement`](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/top-level-api.html#react.createelement) method.

For example the following JSX:

```
<p>Hello World</p>
```

Will be transpiled to:

```
"use strict";

React.createElement(
  "p",
  null,
  "Hello World"
);
```

To be more specific, what happens during the transpilation step is that the nodes of the Abstract Syntax Three (AST) are traversed and transformed. In other words, Babel takes an AST and traverses through it, adding, updating, and removing nodes as it goes along to eventually generate the `React.createElement` function call. *So to be clear, React doesn't handle the transformation of JSX at all*.

To summarize the transpilation process handled by Babel:

1. Parse; take code and output an AST.
2. Transform; traverse AST and manipulate nodes.
3. Generate; take the final AST and turn it back into a string of code.

This also explaines why you **always** have to have `React` in scope when using it in combination with JSX, because otherwise the function call will fail.

Babel exposes the JSX transformation functionality via a [plugin](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-react-jsx/). Bonus: you can actually modify the function call to which the JSX will be transpiled to via the `pragma` option. This allows you to use JSX in combination with a different View Library than React, for example [deku](https://github.com/anthonyshort/deku). You could specify this in your `.babelrc` file:

```
{
  "plugins": [
    ["transform-react-jsx", {
      "pragma": "dom" // default pragma is React.createElement
    }]
  ]
}
```

Additional resources:

- You can see the transpilation result [here](https://babeljs.io/repl/#?evaluate=true&lineWrap=false&presets=es2015%2Creact%2Cstage-2&code=%3Cp%3EHello%20World%3C%2Fp%3E).
- You can visualize the AST [here](http://astexplorer.net/#/Fb4cSdMQdk).
- You can read more about how Babel handles the transpilation [here](https://github.com/thejameskyle/babel-handbook/blob/master/translations/en/plugin-handbook.md).

Answer (score 1):

[JSX in depth](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/jsx-in-depth.html) by React might help understand that better. But, basically

```
var app = <YoucComponent/>; //JSX
var app = React.createElement(YourComponent); //JS
```

You can just do the JS syntax without using JSX just fine, if you don't want to have some transpiler when you develop a React app.